# Mongo collection.insert() fails

Tags: mongodb, rest, insert

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
   data= { "name": "xyz",
           "email": "xyz",
           "number":"123",
           "message":"xyz"
   };
   db.collection('messages').insert(data,function(err,result){
      if(err){
         console.log("error in insertion");
      }
      else
         console.log('insertion success');
   });
    /*******************************************
    sendMail(config);
    Find parameters to send the message too
    ********************************************/

    sendMail(true,mailOptions);
    //db.close();
    console.log('Connection with MongoDB is terminated');
});
```

In the code presented, the sendMail function is executed. However, the .insert is not executed because I do not see the entry in my database.

Can someone tell me how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: sendMail should be called inside insert() function callback

Comment: @SarathNair: Sure, makes sense. But that does not solve the insert issue.   I do not see the data in my database, nor do I see the error message in the callback function.

Comment: are you running the code with commented db.close() ?

Comment: @SarathNair: Thanks. The callback function is called after the transaction with the DB is complete and not just after the insert operation. It works fine now.